# Ajax form that has double submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

So I am sure we have all seen the great ajax forms online that allow you to fill out a form and then hit submit and the area then changes. Like this one:

[Ajax Form](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/09/fancy-contact-form/demo.php)

But I was hoping to get a double submit form. Example would be, someone fills in their phone number, and the form changes and then gives them another box they have to enter in a confirmation code into, because the first submit sent them a confirmation code to their phone. So once they hit submit the second time - it would then respond accordingly.

Has anyone seen one like this, or has anyone done one or knows how to do one?

Comment: The concept is simple. The first form will submit the appropriate info (which then sends the email) via AJAX request. Once the calback has been called (meaning, the server-side processing has finished), the 2nd form will come up with its own set of input to be submitted again.

Answer (score 1):

Have the first click's handling function change the layout around, bind a new function to the button it was clicked to, and then unbind itsself with $.unbind

Answer (score 0):

You can do in below steps:

1. First take input phone number and submit form with the help of AJAX
2. Generate random number and save it in database with the phone number or user_id associated with that phone number with date and time
3. First form will be hidden and second one will be displayed
4. On submit second form, just check the input number against the saved number.